# Macro just for specific cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I got the following macro in my workbook:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
' Clear the color of all the cells
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
If IsEmpty(Target) Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveCell
    ' Highlight the row and column that contain the active cell, within the current region
    Range(Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Range(Cells(.CurrentRegion.Row, .Column), Cells(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + .CurrentRegion.Row - 1, .Column)).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But **I would like it to work just on the cells `F8:IR254`**, which is a region matrix.

Currently it works in every cell which contains a region name, also outside the matrix.

Would that be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You must add those lines of code at the beginning of your Sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("F8:IR254")
    If intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the function `Application.Intersect()` to know if two (or more) ranges have a common part or not.

Please find your amended code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If IsEmpty(Target) Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F8:IR254")) Is Nothing Then
    'Clear the color of all the cells
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveCell
        ' Highlight the row and column that contain the active cell, within the current region
        Range(Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        Range(Cells(.CurrentRegion.Row, .Column), Cells(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + .CurrentRegion.Row - 1, .Column)).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Else
    'Outside of matrix
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this also worked just like Mielks answer. For me as a newbie with VBA, Mielks answer is easier to follow. Thanks anyway!